# How to handle simultaneous updates on a variable in Ver.tx?

Tags: multithreading, vert.x

I am new to Vert.x. I have one scenario in which I need to make a count for all incoming request into a verticle ‒ which is serving as a REST API.

If I just increment the counter for all request, then for simultaneous requests, the value won't be correct ‒ as it will be updating by all requests at same time. It will be same as multiple threads updating a variable simultaneously.

How to handle such scenario in Vert.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to implement a verticle (and a handler) to do the counting/aggregation. Every time you receive a request, you would publish a message to that address (nothing really) and when the verticle receives it, do the math ‒ just add one. If you need the `count` value, you would need another handler for that. One thing to keep in mind is that you would need to instantiate **only one** of these ‒ if you have a cluster the problem complicates a little bit more.

But, why would you do any of that since Vert.x provides something out-of-the-box called **[Asynchronous counters](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_asynchronous_counters)**. This locks though, but that would be one of the easiest ways to accomplish that task in a cluster.